# How to load Jquery plugin/script when Vue router changes page?

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've looked around on here for answers and none of the already supplied ones work for me.

here is a working demo [codepen.io/figaro/pen/mBvWJa](http://codepen.io/figaro/pen/mBvWJa)

My project is simple, a one pager with Vue to handle the page routing. I have some jQuery based content on each different page. When I first load a page, the jQuery plugin displays fine. But when I navigate to other pages, the jQuery plugin does not get reloaded. I've tried every since hook I can think of...mounted, beforeRouteEnter, beforeRouteLeave, updated etc and none of them work. I've tried using  this.$nextTick(function () {} and that does not work either.

The jQuery plugin is slick carousel. Yes I know there is an official vue slick wrapper for this, but I am not using the CLI....my project just has vue and vue router attached through a CDN and I don't understand how to use it with how my project is set up (their examples are for single file components). I don't care if the solution is hacky or not best practice, I just need to make Vue load the slick initializer script on each page. I saw examples to make a directive or component but they don't make sense to me since they are assuming you are using single file components which I am not. Is there any way to do this?

```
main.js 

  const NotFoundPage = {
  name: "NotFoundPage",
  template: "#404-template"
};

const routes = [
  { path: "/", component: Industry },
  { path: "/about", component: My Page },
  { path: "/contact", component: About},
  { path: "*", component: NotFoundPage }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
});

new Vue({
  router,
  template: "#root-template",
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
    })
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate ( to, from , next ) {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
    })
  },
  ready: function() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
    })
  },
  updated () {
  }
}).$mount("#app");
```

html

```
<div id="app"></div>

 <template id="root-template">
 ...stuff

<view-router></view-router>

</template>

 <template id="industry"></template> etc
```

jquery script

```
$('.gallery-responsive').slick({
  infinite: true,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  draggable: true,
  edgeFriction: 0.30,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1100,
    settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
    }
}, {
    breakpoint: 900,
    settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
    }
}, {
    breakpoint: 800,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      dots: false,
      arrows: false,
    }
}
]

});
```

here is a working demo [codepen.io/figaro/pen/mBvWJa](http://codepen.io/figaro/pen/mBvWJa)

Comment: Would you please provide a minified working example?

Comment: Yes I can, thank you for asking. Here is a link to a stripped down version ->  https://codepen.io/figaro/pen/mBvWJa      Notice when you change routes the slider code is not reinitialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your demo and fixed it ([check updated pen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zEgaVd)) by using `next`.

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(vm => {
    $(".single-item").slick({
      dots: true
    });
  })
}
```

The problem is that you tried to use slick before html elements in the component are completely established. In contrast, `next` is invoked [on the end of the navigation resolution flow](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html).

Comment: Thanks a million, I really appreciate it. I knew I was missing something when I went over the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it even better by exposing init function in your script to a `window` object:

```
function slickInit() {
  $('.gallery-responsive').slick({});
}

window.slickInit = slickInit;
```

Then in your `mounted()` hook you can call it:

```
window.slickInit()
```

Or in beforeRouteEnter:

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  next(() => {
    window.slickInit()
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has come here because their jQuery code will only work with Vue when a page is hard loaded (i.e. doesn't work when the page loads via a router redirect), you can just move your jQuery code into `mounted()` and it will work.

Basically you need to wait until the page is ready before running the jQuery code.